# What's the furthest Lee Sin can travel with his W or Q?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there a limit to the distance that Lee can travel with these abilities? We've all probably seen how a Q goes if the enemy flashes behind their team after Lee casts it a second time.

Is there a set maximum? For example, with the addition of Rek'Sai, what would happen if Lee were to W to her right before she started moving with her ultimate?

Comment: For anyone interested, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMAxHHrY4HA shows a few tries of long distance travel via Thresh lanterns.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no travel distance limit.**

When Lee Sin casts his 2nd Q or W you travel to the target and stop as soon as you "hit" it.

What happens depends on the travel speed of lee sin and his target's travel speed.

- If the target has a higher travel speed, Lee Sin will follow and be dragged along the way.
- If the target has a lower travel speed, Lee Sin will stop as soon as he "hits" the target.

**[BUT, the 2nd Q has a cast range of 1300!](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lee_Sin#Resonating_Strike)**

Comment: Not entirely sure about this. Yes Lee will follow his target if it's faster than his travel speed however if you travel too far you will only reach a certain point (Like with Teleport/Twistedfate ultimate)

Comment: hmmm that's true. i'll try to test it. maybe if there distance between both champs exceeds 1300, lee sin will stop.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=py9jzdUgDi4 in this video Lee Sin is teleported with TF. but this looks a bit buggy

Comment: well yeah but this is a bug. Also he wasn't teleporting far. From personal experience I can tell that you'll just stop at some point.

Comment: @Jutschge Maybe there is a difference to make between : A. The target is teleporting and lee will stop where the tp started and B. The target is faster than Lee, then he will follow ad vitam eternam.